# VLCJ save mediaplayer capture

Tags: java, capture, vlcj

I'm using VLCJ and I wish to save a video clip I'm playing using mediaPlayer.playMedia(); to my desktop. I know this can be accomplished by setting media options using a :sout string but I don't know which options to set and I'm having trouble understanding the example option strings on the web. Could someone help by explaining the following :sout option string?

```
String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}", ":input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0"};
```

I just need an options array that creates an mp4 video using the fileName destination. These options fail/error out for me.

Also, VLCJ seems to be dropping a ton of frames with this error

avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame

by using these options

```
String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp1v,vb=2048,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{mux=mpeg1,dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}", ":input-slave=dshow://hw:0,0" };
```

Comment: Those options are really nothing at all to do with vlcj, rather they are VLC streaming/transcoding options so I would suggest instead to focus on VLC documentation. Probably you want to save the raw stream rather than transcoding it.

Comment: Ay, how would I do that. I was thinking of doing that instead of the whole process. I'm pretty new to VLC and doing a raw dump was my first intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a raw stream, use media options similar to the following when you play the media:

```
String mrl = "your-streaming-mrl";
String[] opts = {"sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=output-file.ext}}"};
```

Clearly you replace "your-streaming-mrl" and "output-file.ext" with whatever is appropriate.

And then:

```
mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, opts);
```

You will need to wait (listen) for a media player "finished" event before your saved file is ready.

You may also need to explicitly invoke `release()` on the media player before your saved file is ready.

Comment: Is there anyway to say, have that raw dump to file but the main file that it's playing doesn't ever finish since it's continually being streamed. Right now the second file is just corrupt =[ Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: I think if you stop the media player, wait for the stopped event, then release the media player, you should be OK. I'm not 100% sure though.